# jQuery Mobile listview styles not refreshing after emptying and dynamically recreating the list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova

I have a listview which has its list items created by javascript code. The first time the code runs, it works fine. The second time it runs, the list is created and works fine, but the jQuery Mobile styling is gone. Searching other threads has led me to try the following lines of code in different places, to no avail:

```
$('#ul').listview('refresh');
```

and

```
$('#ul').listview().listview('refresh');
```

and

```
$('#ul').trigger('create');
```

My listview is declared in html like this:

```
<div ID="myUL" class="nav">
    <ul data-role="listview" ID="ul"></ul>
</div>
```

and the following javascript creates the list items:

```
$.ajax( {
        async: 'false',
        type:'POST',
        url:'[redacted]',
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapRequest,
        success:function processSuccess(data, status, req) {
  var returnString = $(req.responseXML).find("GetMyWebServiceResult").text().split("|");
  $("#ul").children().remove('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      var addressString = returnString[i].split(";");
      //create list item 
      var myList = document.getElementById("ul");
      var liSold = document.createElement("li");
      var aTag = document.createElement('a');
      aTag.innerHTML = addressString[0];
      aTag.setAttribute('onClick','somefunction(i)');
      aTag.setAttribute('data-transition','slide');
      liSold.appendChild(aTag);
      myList.appendChild(liSold);
  }
  $('#ul').listview('refresh');
},
error: function(e){
   alert('error 2: ' + e);

}

})
```

Also, I'm doing this in a phonegap (cordova) app, if that makes a difference.

EDIT Additional details:
The page div is not in focus anymore when the list is recreated. Also, the js code snippet is located in a function that is called when a webservice is successfully consumed.

Answer (score 0):

it is wrong with list id.try

```
$('#myUL').listview('refresh');
```